# What is the value of the log-likelihood returned by anova() function

Tags: r

I am performing model selection for a bunch of nested models using the `anova()` function in R. Each subsequent model has the addition of a single covariate to the previous model. I am wondering how the `logLik` column is derived. I understand that it is the natural logarithm of something (i.e. in the model below it is a *very* small number), but what I do not know is exactly *what* it is a logarithm of. Is it the maximum likelihood estimate under that model, i.e. a single value, or is it the result of the multiplication of the probabilities of numerous parameter values? Apologies, I know this is a fairly fundamental thing not to know.

```
Model df      AIC      BIC logLik   Test L.Ratio p.value
    1 11 1319.522 1353.349 -648.8                   
    2 12 1320.547 1357.450 -648.3 1 vs 2   0.975   0.324
    3 13 1314.144 1354.121 -644.1 2 vs 3   8.404   0.004
    4 14 1314.880 1357.932 -643.4 3 vs 4   1.264   0.261
    5 15 1316.872 1363.000 -643.4 4 vs 5   0.007   0.931
    6 16 1318.314 1367.517 -643.2 5 vs 6   0.558   0.455
    7 17 1320.067 1372.345 -643.0 6 vs 7   0.247   0.619
```

Comment: this might be more appropriate for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) ... the numbers are the log-likelihoods (actually technically log-likelihood *densities*) of the entire data set under each model (at the maximum likelihood estimates for that model); because the individual observations are assumed to be independent, the likelihoods of each model is the product of the likelihoods of the individual observations, or equivalently the log-likelihood is the sum of the log-likelihoods of the individual observations ...

Comment: Sorry @Ben Bolker, yes I know this is more of a CV question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers in the `logLik` column are the log-likelihoods (actually technically log-likelihood *densities*) of the entire data set under each model (at the maximum likelihood estimates for that model); because the individual observations are assumed to be independent, the likelihood of each model is the product of the likelihoods of the individual observations, or equivalently the log-likelihood is the sum of the log-likelihoods of the individual observations ...

Comment: Thank you @Ben Bolker. At last I get an answer. And just for my own edification how do we obtain the likelihood of each individual observation?

Comment: depends on the type of model. If you have, say, a linear model with `y=a+bx`, then `dnorm(y,mean=a+b*x,sd=<sd>,log=TRUE)` would give you the log-likelihoods (you'd have to figure out the standard deviation <sd> too). That's not how the model is actually fitted, though.

Comment: so @Ben Bolker the likelihood for each observation in the sample is obtained by plugging the value for that observation into a (in this case) normal distribution whose shape is determined by the characteristics of the entire sample (i.e. the sample's mean and sd)?

Comment: more or less. (Your description is only technically correct for a trivial model, i.e. all the data are in a single group, no continuous predictors, etc etc.)  If you need more, you should *really* ask an appropriate question on CV ...

Comment: Thank you @Ben Bolker for your patience. Your answers were very helpful to me.